# Rails multiple has_one associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, has-one

I have multiple models with created_by and modified_by columns. This is what I have for a Deal Model.

```
class Deal
  has_one :user , :foreign_key => 'created_by'
  has_one :user , :foreign_key => 'modified_by'
end

class User
  belongs_to :created_by , :class_name => 'Deal' , :foreign_key => 'created_by'
  belongs_to :modified_by , :class_name => 'Deal' , :foreign_key => 'modified_by'
end
```

When I create the deal, looks like it is saving correctly. But in the show view when I try to get `@deal.created_by.email` I get an "undefined method `email`" error. Can some tell me how to get this working please?

Also since I have multiple models with these two columns, there can be many belongs_to in User model. Is there an elegant solution for this case?

Answer (score 4):

First thing you have to add is the specification of accessible attributes.
In User you would have to add:

```
attr_accessible :email, :created_by, :modified_by
```

In Deal:

```
attr_accessible :created_by, :modified_by
```

But you should also change the direction of your relation. The foreign_key is always on the belongs_to side.

This is what worked for me:

```
class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :created_by, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "created_by"
  belongs_to  :modified_by, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key =>"modified_by"

  attr_accessible :created_by, :modified_by, :name
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :created_deals, :class_name => "Deal", :foreign_key => "created_by"
  has_many :modified_deals, :class_name => "Deal", :foreign_key => "modified_by"

  attr_accessible :created_deals, :modified_deals, :name
end
```

If you have more models, which look similiar you could probably use polymorphic associations: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

Answer (score 2):

First of all, from my experience it is generally a bad idea to have associations using the foreign key as name. Especially when writing fixtures it seems rails will get confused between setting the actual value "created_by" or the model in the created_by association. In my models I generally use these associations for the cases you describe:

```
belongs_to :creator, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => 'created_by'
belongs_to :modifier, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => 'modified_by'
```

You can use association names like 'creating_user' instead if you prefer. If you really want created_by as association name you should have created_by_id or something similar as foreign key, just as long as its not equal to the association name.

Then I am a bit confused by your pasted code. Your choice "Deal has_one User" and "User belongs_to Deal" means that the users table will have the columns created_by and modified_by (foreign keys) containing Deal Ids, basically meaning that users get created by a single deal? However it seems like deals should get created by users and not the other way round. Your example of deal.created_by.email can not work at all with your associations, since deal would not have an association called "created_by", only "user", of which you have two associations with the same name in a single model which can not work at all in the first place.

Fixing your associations similar to what Patrick suggested:

```
class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :creator, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "created_by"
  belongs_to  :modifier, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key =>"modified_by"
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :created_deals, :class_name => "Deal", :foreign_key => "created_by"
  has_many :modified_deals, :class_name => "Deal", :foreign_key => "modified_by"
end
```